# IP calculator. Decimal to binary

Tags: vbscript

I have ploblem with converting decimal numbers to binary. I want to have space between 8b, but i dont know how to do that in the code.

```
Function str2bin(strAddress) 
'special decimal to binary function
'input 4 octet ip address 
'output 32bit binary number


   objAddress = Split(strAddress, ".") 
   For Each strOctet In objAddress 

      intOctet = CInt  (strOctet)
      strOctBin = "" 
      For x = 1 To 8 
         If intOctet Mod 2 > 0 Then 
            strOctBin = "1" & strOctBin 
         Else 
            strOctBin = "0" & strOctBin 
         End If 
         intOctet = Int(intOctet / 2) 
      Next 
      str2bin = str2bin & strOctBin 
   Next 

End Function 


'-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: "I want to have space between 8b" -- what is "8b"?

Comment: space between every 8 number. 8b=8 byte

Comment: I've put my code here. Please solve the problem cuz i really dont know. i havent worked with visual basic :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ```
> 'Subnet Calculator V1
> 'Script by Chavdarova
>
> 'usage cscript VBScriptSubnetCalcV2 > output.txt
>
>
>    'force script to run in cscript mode
>    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
>    If Instr(1, WScript.FullName, "CScript", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
>       objShell.Run "%comspec% /k cscript //nologo """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """", 1, False
>       WScript.Quit
>    End If
>
>
>
>
>    'a bit of test code to feed a range of addresses into script for testing
> '   snm="255.255.192.0"
>
> '   for iCount=0 to 255
> '      ip="172.16.17."&iCount
> '      CalcSubnet ip, snm
> '   next
>
>
>    strIP=inputbox("Vnesite IP", "Chavdarova Subnet Calc", "172.16.98.53")
>    strSN=inputbox("Vnesite Subnet Mask", "Chavdarova Subnet Calc", "255.255.224.0")
>
>    CalcSubnet strIP, strSN
>
>    wscript.quit
>
>
> ----------
> function CalcSubnet(strIP,strSNM)
>
>    binSNM=str2bin(strSNM) 
>    binIP=str2bin(strIP) 
>
>
>    'IP <AND> SN to find Network addresses
>    for c=32 to 1 step -1
>       temp=(cint(mid(binIP,c, 1)) and cint(mid(binSNM,c, 1))) & temp
>    next
>    netwAdd=temp : temp=""
>
>
>
>    'IP <OR> SN to find blocks of all "ones" - these addresss are broadcast addresses
>    for c=32 to 1 step -1
>       temp=(cint(mid(binIP,c, 1)) or cint(mid(binSNM,c, 1))) & temp
>    next
>    bcCheck=temp : temp=""
>
>
>
>
>    'Calc 1st. host address in range (Network Address + 1)
>    ist=binAdd(netwAdd,string(31, "0")&"1")
>
>    'Calc Last host address in range (111111...1 - bcCheck + IP - 0...000001)
>    lst=binSub(string(32,"1"),bcCheck) 
>    lst=binadd(lst,binIP)
>    lst=binsub(lst,string(31, "0")&"1" )
>
>
>    wscript.echo "IP               "&binIP&" "&bin2str(binIP)&vbcrlf&_
>              "Subnet Mask      "&binSNM&" "&bin2str(binSNM)&vbcrlf&_              
>              "Subnet Network   "&netwAdd&" "&bin2str(netwAdd)&vbcrlf&_           
>              "Host min         "&ist &" "& bin2str(ist) &vbcrlf&_
>              "Host max         "&lst &" "& bin2str(lst) &vbcrlf&_
>              "Hosts            "&binsub(lst,ist) &" "& Bin2Dec(binsub(lst,ist)) &vbcrlf
>
>
> end function
>
>
> ----------
> Function Bin2Dec(strBin)
> 'Plain old binary to decimal function
>
>    result = 0
>    for intIndex = len(strBin) to 1 step -1
>       strDigit = mid(strBin, intIndex, 1)
>
>
>
>  if strDigit = "0" then
>          'do nothing
>       elseif strDigit = "1" then
>          result = result + (2 ^ (len(strBin)-intIndex))
>       else
>          Bin2Dec = 0
>          exit for
>       end if
>
>    next
>
>    Bin2Dec = result
>
> End Function
>
>
> ----------
> Function bin2str(strBinary)
> 'special binary to decimal function
> 'input 32bit binary number
> 'output 4 octet ip address 
>
>    For iPosOct = 1 To 4 
>       strOctBin = Right(Left(strBinary, iPosOct * 8), 8) 
>       intOctet = 0 
>       intValue = 1 
>       For iPosBin = 1 To Len(strOctBin) 
>          If Left(Right(strOctBin, iPosBin), 1) = "1" Then 
>             intOctet = intOctet + intValue 
>          end if
>          intValue = intValue * 2 
>       Next 
>       If bin2str = Empty Then 
>          bin2str = CStr(intOctet) 
>       Else 
>          bin2str = bin2str & "." & CStr(intOctet)
>       end if 
>    Next 
>
> End Function 
>
>
> ----------
> Function str2bin(strAddress) 
> 'special decimal to binary function
> 'input 4 octet ip address 
> 'output 32bit binary number
>
>    objAddress = Split(strAddress, ".") 
>    For Each strOctet In objAddress 
>
>
>
>      intOctet = CInt  (strOctet)
>       strOctBin = "" 
>       For x = 1 To 8 
>
>
>     If intOctet Mod 2 > 0 Then 
>             strOctBin = "1" & strOctBin 
>          Else 
>             strOctBin = "0" & strOctBin 
>          End If 
>          intOctet = Int(intOctet / 2) 
>       Next 
>       str2bin = str2bin & strOctBin & " "
>
>
>    Next 
>
> End Function 
>
>
> ----------
> function binSub(binA,binB)
> 'subtract one 32bit binary number from another
> 'binA must be biggest
>
>    c=0
>    for i=32 to 1 step-1
>       a=cint(mid(binA,i,1))
>       b=cint(mid(binB,i,1))
>
>
>
>       if a=0 and b=0 and c=0 then 
>          subt=0   : c=0 
>       elseif a=1 and b=0 and c=0 then 
>          subt=1  : c=0 
>       elseif a=0 and b=1 and c=0 then 
>          subt=1  : c=1 
>       elseif a=1 and b=1 and c=0 then 
>          subt=0  : c=0 
>       elseif a=1 and b=1 and c=1 then 
>         subt=1  : c=1
>       elseif a=1 and b=0 and c=1 then 
>          subt=0  : c=0
>       elseif a=0 and b=1 and c=1 then 
>          subt=0  : c=0 
>       elseif a=0 and b=0 and c=1 then 
>          subt=1  : c=1
>       else
>          msgbox "This function is only for subtracting 2 32bit binary numbers"
>          binSub=0 : exit function
>       end if            
>
>       total=subt&total
>       'wscript.echo "a-"&BinA&" "&a&vbcrlf&"b-"&BinB&" "&b&vbcrlf&"subtraction "&subt&vbcrlf&"carry "&
> ```
>
> c&vbcrlf&"x-"&total&vbcrlf&cvcrlf
>
> ```
>    next
>
>    if c=1 then 
>       msgbox "Error you are subtracting a larger number from a smaller number"&vbcrlf&binA&vbcrlf&binB
>    end if
>
>    binsub=total
>
> end function
>
>
> ----------
>
>
> function binAdd(binA,binB)
> 'add two 32bit binary numbers together
>
>    c=0
>    for i=32 to 1 step-1
>       a=cint(mid(binA,i,1))
>       b=cint(mid(binB,i,1))
>       if a=0 and b=0 and c=0 then 
>          add=0  : c=0 
>       elseif a=1 and b=0 and c=0 then 
>          add=1  : c=0 
>       elseif a=0 and b=1 and c=0 then 
>          add=1  : c=0 
>       elseif a=1 and b=1 and c=0 then 
>          add=0  : c=1 
>       elseif a=1 and b=1 and c=1 then 
>         add=1  : c=1
>       elseif a=1 and b=0 and c=1 then 
>          add=0  : c=1
>       elseif a=0 and b=1 and c=1 then 
>          add=0  : c=1 
>       elseif a=0 and b=0 and c=1 then 
>          add=1  : c=0
>       else
>          msgbox "Error this function is only for adding 2 32bit binary numbers together"
>          binAdd=0 : exit function
>       end if
>
>       total=add&total
>       'wscript.echo "a-"&BinA&" "&a&vbcrlf&"b-"&BinB&" "&b&vbcrlf&"addition "&add&vbcrlf&"carry "& c&vbcrlf&"x-"&total
>
>    next
>
>    binAdd=total
>
> end function
> ```

Comment: This isn't an answer.  If you want to include code with your question, then edit the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and very dirty:

Append a space after each octet:

```
str2bin = str2bin & strOctBin & " "
```

and `Trim()` the return value in the calling code to get rid of the trailing space.

**Evidence:**

```
type 28139908.vbs & cscript 28139908.vbs
Option Explicit

Function str2bin(strAddress)
'special decimal to binary function
'input 4 octet ip address
'output 32bit binary number
   Dim objAddress, strOctet, intOctet, strOctBin, x
   objAddress = Split(strAddress, ".")
   For Each strOctet In objAddress

      intOctet = CInt  (strOctet)
      strOctBin = ""
      For x = 1 To 8
         If intOctet Mod 2 > 0 Then
            strOctBin = "1" & strOctBin
         Else
            strOctBin = "0" & strOctBin
         End If
         intOctet = Int(intOctet / 2)
      Next
      str2bin = str2bin & strOctBin & " "
   Next
End Function

Dim sIP : sIP = "127.15.32.255"
WScript.Echo sIP, ">" & str2bin(sIP) & "<", ">" & Trim(str2bin(sIP)) & "<"
127.15.32.255 >01111111 00001111 00100000 11111111 < >01111111 00001111 00100000 11111111<
```

Comment: @kamelija77 - nothing is impossible - see Evidence